# VBA IF condition with an error that just works for the first loop

Tags: excel, vba, if-statement, conditional-statements, dashboard

I am trying to create a graph using VBA. First of all, I have a dashboard and I would like to have a main sheet that summarize some name that I want to search for, so all my data are in other sheets.

I am trying to create a VBA IF condition that search for a specific name, which the names in the data sheet are like this:

[data sheet](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Q6LSS.png)

With that in mind, I dim an "i" to find the name that I want in the data sheet. When someone wants to search for name1 or name 2..., the person will choose the name in main sheet, which the cell is: "C3". If C3 cell in main sheet is equal to the data sheet B2 or Q2... then create a graph.

```
If Worksheets("data").Cells(2, i) = Worksheets("main").Cells(3, 3) Then
```

The thing is that this condition just works for the first name and I dont know why. Also there is an error that says:

> Run-time error "13": Type mismatch

The full vba code that I have:´

```
Sub graph()

Dim chrt As ChartObject
Dim i As Long
Dim LastRow As Long
Dim LastColumn As Long

'Find the last used row
LastRow = Sheets("vol").Range("B65536").End(xlUp).Row

'Find the last used column
LastColumn = 500

'Looping from second row till last row which has the data
For i = 2 To LastColumn

If Worksheets("vol").Cells(2, i) = Worksheets("main").Cells(3, 3) Then

  'Sheet main is selected bcoz charts will be inserted here
    Sheets("main").Select

    ActiveSheet.Shapes.AddChart.Select
    'this adds the chart and selects it in the same statement
    ActiveChart.ChartType = xlLine

    'now the line chart is added...setting its data source here
    ActiveChart.SeriesCollection.NewSeries
    ActiveChart.SeriesCollection(1).Name = "25%"
    ActiveChart.SeriesCollection(1).XValues = Worksheets("data").Range(Worksheets("data").Cells(6, i), Worksheets("data").Cells(LastRow, i))
    ActiveChart.SeriesCollection(1).Values = Worksheets("data").Range(Worksheets("data").Cells(6, i + 1), Worksheets("data").Cells(LastRow, i + 1))

    'now the line chart is added...setting its data source here
    ActiveChart.SeriesCollection.NewSeries
    ActiveChart.SeriesCollection(2).Name = "50%"
    ActiveChart.SeriesCollection(2).XValues = Worksheets("data").Range(Worksheets("data").Cells(6, i), Worksheets("data").Cells(LastRow, i))
    ActiveChart.SeriesCollection(2).Values = Worksheets("data").Range(Worksheets("data").Cells(6, i + 6), Worksheets("data").Cells(LastRow, i + 6))

    'now the line chart is added...setting its data source here
    ActiveChart.SeriesCollection.NewSeries
    ActiveChart.SeriesCollection(3).Name = "25%"
    ActiveChart.SeriesCollection(3).XValues = Worksheets("data").Range(Worksheets("data").Cells(6, i), Worksheets("data").Cells(LastRow, i))
    ActiveChart.SeriesCollection(3).Values = Worksheets("data").Range(Worksheets("data").Cells(6, i + 11), Worksheets("data").Cells(LastRow, i + 11))

    With Worksheets("main").ChartObjects(1).Chart
        .HasTitle = True
        .ChartTitle.Text = "1 month"
    End With
    
End If
     
i = i + 15
    
Next i


End Sub
```

Could someone illuminate me, please!!!

Thank you so much

Comment: `Range(Worksheets("data").Cells(6, i), Worksheets("vol").Cells(LastRow, i)` all parts of a range need to be on the same sheet

Comment: What's in each cell when you get the error ?

Comment: `For i = 2 To LastColumn` should be `For i = 2 To LastColumn Step 15` and remove the `i = i + 15` from inside the loop

Comment: @TimWilliams the error is from the condition:  `If Worksheets("vol").Cells(2, i) = Worksheets("main").Cells(3, 3) Then`

Comment: Yes but what are the values in those cells when that happens?

Comment: @TimWilliams I did modify the code as you said: `For i = 2 To LastColumn Step 15` and worked. Thank you so much!!!

Comment: Are you trying to emulate a Data Slicer??

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Some suggested changes, including the `Step 15`

```vb
Sub graph()

    Dim cht As Chart, co As Object
    Dim i As Long
    Dim LastRow As Long, rngX As Range, rngY As Range
    Dim LastColumn As Long, wsMain As Worksheet, wsVol As Worksheet, wsData As Worksheet

    Set wsVol = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("vol")
    Set wsData = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("data")
    Set wsMain = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Main")
    
    For i = 2 To 500 Step 15 'loop in increments of 15
    
        If wsVol.Cells(2, i) = wsMain.Cells(3, 3) Then
            'define data ranges
            Set rngX = wsData.Range(wsData.Cells(6, i), wsData.Cells(Rows.Count, i).End(xlUp))
            Set rngY = rngX.Offset(0, 1)
            
            ClearWorksheetCharts wsMain 'remove any existing chart(s)
            With wsMain.Range("B26:F37")
                'add chartobject, setting position and size
                Set co = .Worksheet.Shapes.AddChart(xlLine, .Left, .Top, _
                                                     .Width, .Height)
            End With
            
            Set cht = co.Chart
            ClearChartSeries cht 'remove any "auto-added" series (if data was selected when chart was added)
            
            AddSeries cht, "25%", rngX, rngY
            AddSeries cht, "50%", rngX, rngY.Offset(0, 5)
            AddSeries cht, "25%", rngX, rngY.Offset(0, 10)
            
            cht.HasTitle = True
            cht.ChartTitle.Text = "1 month"

            With cht.Axes(xlCategory, xlPrimary)'X axis name
                .HasTitle = True 
                .AxisTitle.Characters.Text = "Time" 
            End With
            With cht.Axes(xlValue, xlPrimary)
                .HasTitle = True 
                .AxisTitle.Characters.Text = "Value"
            End With

         End If
    Next i
End Sub

'add a series and name it (factored out from main sub)
Sub AddSeries(cht As Chart, serName As String, serX, serY)
    With cht.SeriesCollection.NewSeries
        .Name = serName
        .XValues = serX
        .Values = serY
    End With
End Sub

'remove any existing series from a chart
Sub ClearChartSeries(cht As Chart)
    Do While cht.SeriesCollection.Count > 0
        cht.SeriesCollection(1).Delete
    Loop
End Sub

'Remove any chart objects from `ws`
Sub ClearWorksheetCharts(ws As Worksheet)
    Do While ws.ChartObjects.Count > 0
        ws.ChartObjects(1).Delete
    Loop
End Sub
```

Comment: Thank you, that worked smoothly! Now I am  trying to set a graph location in the main sheet, but it didn't work: `Sub Location(cht As ChartObject)
    Set wsMain = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Main").ChartObjects(1)
    With cht
        .Top = Range("B26").Top
        .Width = Range("B26:F37").Width
        .Height = Range("B26:F37").Height
    End With
End Sub`     What I did wrong, @TimWilliams?

Comment: Besides that, I would like to delete (if there is) some previous graph that was created with the same code, I tried to use this code in this location           ` ...  wsVol.ChartObjects.Delete
    
       For i = 2 To 500 Step 15 'loop in increments of 15
        
            If wsVol.Cells(2, i) = wsMain.Cells(3, 3) Then... ` 

What I did wrong, @TimWilliams?

Comment: See edits above

Comment: Thank you so much, it works!! I have two more questions and I promise that I won´t bother you anymore. The first one is: I would like to reverse the X value and tried to use ' .Axes(xlValue).ReversePlotOrder = True' and it didn´t work.( But in consequence of a reverse change in the x value, the y value should change as well and I don´t know how to do it.) The second question is: I would like to name the X value as "Time" and Y value as "Value". Thank you again @TimWilliams

Comment: `cht.Axes(xlCategory).ReversePlotOrder = True` should work for the x-axis

Comment: For axis titles see https://www.mrexcel.com/board/threads/adding-in-axis-titles-using-vba.979449/

Comment: FYI you can get all of this syntax (or a least a start on it) by using the macro recorder while making the changes you want.